# How to use stack in compiler semantic analysis?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree, semantics

I have the following code which uses the nodes from an AST and executes steps based on which kind of node it is.

```
switch (kind(*node)) {
        case(scope_node):
        case(declarations):
        case(statements):
        case(declaration):
        case(statement):
 }
```

For example, if I have the declaration node representing something like

```
int a = 5;
```

I know that the AST will treat that as a declaration node, then a statement node, integer node etc.
I want to allocate a stack for each kind of node so that I can keep track of the 'children' of that node and call the appropriate functions as I pop them off the stack.

Semantic Analyzer:
In terms of design of the semantic analyzer using the AST nodes, would it be most feasible to have the stack as a function that I would call that would allocate and deallocate the stack once all the children have been visited? Or would it make more sense to create an object or structure?

Any help is appreciated! Any visuals and examples would be really helpful.

Comment: Usually ASTs are represented as tree-like structures. They are built during parsing, and if you are using a parser generator, there will likely be a simple mechanism to get the components. Without more context, it is hard to provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Yes, I am able to get the components as I traverse through the tree (i.e. the nodes) but I am wondering how to best use that information and how best to store it to check for semantic errors?

Comment: @ce1 why do you need to store it again? Isn't all the information in the AST already? Why duplicate the data?